# Upper/lower case ranking problem in Google - How to remove in Webmasters?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, url, search-engine-indexing

I have only this single URL on my website:

```
https://www.aadseducation.com/isms-lead-auditor-training/details
```

Previously, this URL because of a mistake done by developer, Google started ranking the upper case URL:

```
https://www.aadseducation.com/ISMS-Lead-Auditor-training/details
```

I have changed the URL casing structure mistake that has been done on the front-end. Now how do I submit URL to Google to ensure the lower case one retains the ranking?

Screenshot of the case:

[image: Uppercase URL - SERP Google]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 301 redirect the old URL, so that anyone (or anybot) with the old link sees it's been moved.
2. If possible, also add a canonical to the page as an additional confirmation to anyone and anybot that the lowercase version is the right one.

Comment: Hi, actually there are not two different pages. It is because of the capitalization, the SE is treating them as different pages. Now I have got the developer fix the casing so that any upper case when entered, will be automatically converted to lower case and the page canonical URL is correct. Is thing enough?

Or

Are you suggesting me to have the upper case URL and put the canonical to lower case? A 301 Redirect is not possible because the upper case page does not exist really and due to the coding, any upper case automatically transforms to lowercase.

Comment: You don't need (or want) two separate pages. If Google is still seeing the uppercase version, "the coding" may not have been done properly, or it may just be that Google needs more time to update. You should use a HTTP Header Checker, paste in the uppercase URL, and check whether you get a 301 response. If you get a 302 or 200, that's when you need to have your developer change the functionality and do a full 301 (permanent) redirect. That way visitors and bots will still automatically get to the right page, but they'll also get a notice that the uppercase URL is old.

Comment: Yes it is a 301 Redirect. Seems I should give Google more time to update.